# How do you hide an article title in BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex

I can use

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,url=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
```

to hide urls and dois from my bibliography, but

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,url=false,doi=false,title=false]{biblatex}
```

will not compile, throwing instead a keyval error.

*How can I hide the titles of articles from my bibliography?*

Comment: Is `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}` what you are after? Or alternatively, `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}`.

Comment: @Corentin, Would I put this somewhere in the header of the LaTeX document source?

Comment: Yes, `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}` is working when placed in the header.

Comment: Yes, in the preamble of your document.

Answer (score 7):

1. You can use `\DeclareSourceMap`:

   ```
   \DeclareSourcemap{
     \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
       \map{
         \pertype{article}
          \step[fieldset=title, null]
       }
    }
   }
   ```
2. You can change the field format of title:

   ```
   \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}
   ```

Both solutions can be done at the preamble.

Comment: Please note that `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{}` can have adverse effects in that it makes `biblatex` think it printed the title when it didn't, potentially messing up the punctuation. The preferred variant is probably `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}`/`\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}`.