# \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{Title}} in beamer?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

In my beamer presentation, I want to cite the reference without title. So, I tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex8,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=none,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  uniquelist=false,
  refsegment=section,
  citestyle=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mini.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{Title}}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}
\begin{frame}
  first cite\footfullcite{Julie2006}
  %\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\section{2nd}
\begin{frame}
  Second cite\footfullcite{gyof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the mini.bib :

```
@article{gyof,
  Author={BLJ},
  Title={Some Title},
  Journal={joural1},
  volume={15},
  pages={1337},
  Year={1985}
}
@article{Julie2006,
  Author={JBS},
  Title={Some Other Title},
  Journal={journal2},
  volume={74},
  pages={144411},
  Year={2006}
}
```

with `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{Title}}` I was expecting no title will be produced, but thats not the case:
[image: the output]

Is there any incompatibility between clearfield and footfullcite? Or I am just missing something?

Comment: See also [Remove title in biblatex references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141822/35864) and [How do you hide an article title in BibLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142927/35864).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since `\fullfootcite` (and `\fuulcite`) are still technically cite commands, we need to use `\AtEveryCitekey` to hook into and not `\AtEveryBibitem`, even though they copy the behaviour of the bibliography driver.

So the solution is to use

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}
```

Discussions about whether it is a good idea to drop the title have been had elsewhere on this site, so I will just remark that omitting the title might work for `@article`s, but looks odd - at best; at worst it will just be plain confusing and inhibit the reader's ability to locate the work (think of a very productive author that managed to get several books published by the same publisher in one year) - with other entry types, so something along the lines of

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{title}}
    {}}
```

might be better suited.

You might also want to get rid of the "in:" as in [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{title}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\fullcite{moore}

\fullcite{wilde}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget add comment sign, %, after every clearfield, otherwise extra space may be added. My advice is to do it like this, where you can do the same for book as shown:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{title}}{}%
    \ifentrytype{book}
    {\clearfield{series}%
    \clearfield{address}%
    \clearfield{publisher}}{}%
}
```