# Presentation References -- no-title footnotes, allowing arXiv

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

**Background**

---

In a Beamer Presentation I am typesetting, the author wants two things:

1. The author wants both footnote references and an end-of-presentation reference list.
2. In the footnote reference, the author wants to list both the reference's author and the reference's publication information, but *not* the title or any unnecessary URL's.

So far, I have solutions.

1. I can use `biblatex`'s`\footfullcite` or `\footcite` command for footnote references.
2. For the footnote style, the `chem-acs` bibliography style does the trick for the standard bibliography items.

MWE #1: Working Case

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{testArt,
 AUTHOR = {Author, Aa},
  TITLE = {A long title illustrating the need to remove the title from footnote citations, at least in Presentations},
JOURNAL = {Lorem Ipsum Stud.},
 VOLUME = {15},
  PAGES = {1--20},
   YEAR = {1999},
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
An important fact\footfullcite{testArt} is useful for the following results.  
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: A slide with <code>chem-acs</code> reference in footnote]
[image: A reference slide in <code>chem-acs</code> style]

**The Problem**

---

The issue is that the author also wants to cite an `arXiv` article, and if I use the `@online` type of `biblatex` to format the `arXiv` reference, `chem-acs` does not know what to do.  It prints the title, and not any of the `eprint` information.

MWE #2:  Breaking case

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{testAppend.bib}
@article{testArt,
 AUTHOR = {Author, Aa},
  TITLE = {A long title illustrating the need to remove the title from footnote citations, at least in Presentations},
JOURNAL = {Lorem Ipsum Stud.},
 VOLUME = {15},
  PAGES = {1--20},
   YEAR = {1999},
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com},
}
@online{fakearXiv,
     AUTHOR = {Buthor, Bb},
      TITLE = {Not a real arXiv article},
       DATE = {1950-05-01},
 EPRINTTYPE = {arXiv},
     EPRINT = {5005.01},
EPRINTCLASS = {math.GM},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testAppend.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
An important fact\footfullcite{testArt} is useful for the following results.

We also mention the following result.\footfullcite{fakearXiv}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: New first slide, with bad arXiv output in footnote (contains Title, no arXiv information)]
[image: New reference slide, bad arXiv output again]

(`chem-angew` does not give significantly different results -- there's a date, but nothing more).

There are two workable-but-annoying solutions that I can see:

**A.** Manually format all footnote references (using `\nocite` as appropriate), and use a standard bibliography style to get the end-of-presentation references correct.

**B.** Create a new `biblatex` style whose in-text citation style is akin to the desired footnote style (but allows `@online`), and whose bibliography style is any appropriate style.

## The Question

> Is there any other workaround that maintains the author-and-publication format for footnotes, but allows `@online` (and possibly other unusual formats)?

### Objectives

All *I* need are `@article` and `@online` for the present assignment; however, I will try to give more general criteria.  (Thanks to commenter moewe for this suggestion.)

---

A **good** solution will include the following fields for footnote citations of the given varieties, and will not include `title`.  (No formatting requirements for end-of-presentation bibliography; punctuation, formatting, and ordering is flexible.)

`@article`: Author, Journal, Year, Volume (optional Number), Pages.

`@book`: Author, Location:Publisher, (opt. Edition), Year. (optional Volume/Part/etc.)

`@collection`: Editor, Location:Publisher, (opt. Edition), Year. (optional Volume/Part/etc.)

`@incollection`: Author, In: Editor, Location:Publisher, (opt. Edition), Year, Pages.  (optional Volume/Part/etc.)

`@inproceedings`: same, but may add Organization.

`@online`: Author, Year (optional), EPrint.

`@thesis`: Author, (optional Type), Institution, Year.

I think this is enough to get the idea.  Authors/Editors, some field indicating the publisher and/or location (or electronic equivalent), Pages for parts of a source, Year.

(Note: at this level, the answers to [Question 233851](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233581/ateverybibitem-clearfieldtitle-in-beamer) may well be enough.  [Thanks to user moewe for bringing this to my attention.])

---

A **great** solution will do the above, *except* that whenever two sources in the document have the same author and year, one must print the title or short-title (similarly to `authortitle-terse`, if slightly more restrictive).

---

An **excellent** solution will do the above, and have more descriptive end-bibliography files (allowing titles in particular).  (This is probably impossible without effectively making a new bibliography style.)

Comment: I didn't check, but what about the `eprint=true` option?

Comment: @moewe, it appears to be a half-fix.  `eprint=true` in the initial options does force it to display the date and `arXiv` information.  It still has the unnatural title, and arguably the date is unnecesary given the month/year information encoded in the (post-2007) `arXiv` info.

Comment: Ah I see. Just so I understand correctly: Should the citations in the footnotes be exact copies of the references at the end or should the be shorter? In the latter case I think you will have to roll your own citation command. `\footfullcite` really is there to give the full reference as it would appear in the bibliography (give or take a few small details). What exactly do you want to see in the citation for each entry type? You can always go with `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}` but I'm no fan of that (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233581/35864 and linked questions).

Comment: @moewe, the footnote references should be succinct and consistently non-titled, as above (but more than author-year, publication info is necessary).  The end references *can* be longer (and that would be nice), but I am not making it a requirement.

Comment: It's getting quite late where I am and I should get some sleep, but I will have a look at this tomorrow (if it is not solved until then). Until then it would help greatly if you could give an exact definition of what the citations should look like for each entry type involved. I'd be interested in what should be shown for `@book` and `@incolection` for example. Bearing in mind that there could be several books by the same author from the same year published by the same publisher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the information in the footnote citations and the bibliography at the end  differ quite a bit, I think it is necessary to completely re-implement the citations independent of the bibliography, that actually allows you to use this citation style with almost every bibliography style.

The idea is to define a citation macro for each entry type that then prints the short citation you want to see.

The macro `optionallabeltitle` prints the title if there are several entries by the same list of authors from the same year. Currently that macro is only called for `@book`s, because it seemed only relevant there. But you can of course extend this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testArt,
 AUTHOR = {Author, Aa},
  TITLE = {A long title illustrating the need to remove the title from footnote citations, at least in Presentations},
JOURNAL = {Lorem Ipsum Stud.},
 VOLUME = {15},
  PAGES = {1--20},
   YEAR = {1999},
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com},
}
@online{fakearXiv,
     AUTHOR = {Buthor, Bb},
      TITLE = {Not a real arXiv article},
       DATE = {1950-05-01},
 EPRINTTYPE = {arXiv},
     EPRINT = {5005.01},
EPRINTCLASS = {math.GM},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,labeldateparts,eprint=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro{cite:type:article}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}}

\newbibmacro{cite:type:online}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \newunit
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldequalstr{eprinttype}{arXiv}} or
              test {\iffieldequalstr{eprinttype}{arxiv}}}
    {}
    {\printlabeldate}%
  \newunit
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{url}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro{cite:type:book}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{optionallabeltitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{cite:publisher+location+edition+date}}

\newbibmacro{cite:type:collection}{%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{cite:publisher+location+edition+date}}

\newbibmacro{cite:type:incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:type:collection}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}}

\newbibmacro{cite:type:proceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{cite:publisher+location+edition+date}}

\newbibmacro{cite:type:inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:type:proceedings}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}}

\newbibmacro{cite:type:thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlabeldate
}

\newbibmacro*{optionallabeltitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{extradate}
    {}
    {\ifnumgreater{\thefield{extradate}}{0}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:publisher+location+edition+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlabeldate
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\foothalffullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifbibmacroundef{cite:type:\thefield{entrytype}}
     {\blx@warning{No cite macro for entry type '\thefield{entrytype}'.\MessageBreak
        Falling back to full bibldriver}%
      \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
     {\usebibmacro*{cite:type:\thefield{entrytype}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\foothalffullcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\foothalffullcite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{foothalffullcite}{\foothalffullcite}{\foothalffullcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=foothalffullcite}

\begin{document}
An important fact\autocite{testArt} is useful for the following results.

We also mention\autocite{fakearXiv} the following result.\autocite{markey}

Dolor\autocite{knuth:ct:b} sit\autocite{knuth:ct:c} amet\autocite{companion}

Lorem\autocite{westfahl:space} ipsum \autocite{gaonkar:in}

Lorem\autocite{geer} ipsum \autocite{loh}

Lorem\autocite{pines} ipsum \autocite{brandt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: footnotes of the MWE]