# How to remove journal from verbose cite?

Tags: biblatex

I want to remove the journal title and the issue (the yellow part in the screenshot) from the footnote of a citation. The repeating entries can remain as they are. But in the bibliography I still want this information. How can I add different way of using for citations and bibliography? The type of the entry is article.

[image: To be removed parts highlighted]

The bibliography shall stay as it is:
[image: Bibliography]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=ext-verbose-ibid,
isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, eprint=false,
dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    Lorem\autocite{aksin} %article
    ipsum\autocite{angenendt} %article
    dolor\autocite{aksin}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen to other entry types like `@book`, `@incollection` etc.? I outlined general principles to modify `verbose` citation styles just this morning, maybe that helps a bit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542604/35864

Comment: Maybe it helps to ask the question from a different point of view: Not 'what date do you want to remove', but rather 'what data do you want to see in citations?' It would also help if you could explain what you want to see on subsequent (non-"ibid.") citations.

Comment: As explained in my answer to the linked question, the first citations in a `verbose` style use the bibliography driver, so in principle they produce the same output as the bibliography entry. If this is not desired then there are several possible ways around this. But which way is the most promising depends on what you want to happen to other types of entries: If you want to see only author, title and date for all entries then that would be done differently than if you want all other entries to remain as is.

Comment: Since every entry type is a little bit different, I only want to change the way for articles.

Comment: ugh, that's going to be messy. But I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explained the general structure of `verbose` citation styles and approaches to modifying their output just recently in [Customize verbose citation style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542604/35864), so I won't go through the details here again.

The first citation of a work is printed by the bibmacro [`cite:full` (`verbose.cbx`, ll. 93-99 v3.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/verbose.cbx#L93-L99). Essentially that macro just calls the bib driver for the correct entry type. This means that the first citation will look almost exactly like the corresponding entry in the bibliography.

If you want to change that for all entry types, you would just redefine `cite:full` to print something else instead. But if you want to change the output only for `@article`s, you need a more sophisticated approach. One way is to define a new bibmacro `cite:full:article` for `@article`s that prints only the desired data. We would then tell `cite:full` to use `cite:full:article` instead of the driver for `@article` entries.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-verbose-ibid,
  isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, eprint=false,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \ifbibmacroundef{cite:full:\strfield{entrytype}}
      {\usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
         {\thefield{entrytype}}}
      {\usebibmacro*{cite:full:\strfield{entrytype}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\newbibmacro{cite:full:article}{%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Lorem\autocite{aksin} %article
  ipsum\autocite{angenendt} %article
  dolor\autocite{aksin}
  sit\autocite{worman}
  amet\autocite{nussbaum}
  consectur\autocite{sigfridsson}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın, Özge u.a., „Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions“ (2006), S. 3027–3036.]

As discussed in the comments, this changes only first citations of `@article` entries. Subsequent citations and entry types other than `@article` are unaffected. But the scheme can easily be extended to modify the first citations of other entry types. Just define the bibmacro `cite:full:<type>` analogous to `cite:full:article` above.

Comment: One additional question, how do I change given name and familiy name? After the declaration I have the two lines \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} \DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-family} but they don't work anymore for articles.

Comment: @BjörnEngel The name format in `cite:full:article` obeys the same settings as the bibliography. In this case `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` means that you get "Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf". If you want more consistency with other `cite:full` results you can add `\begingroup\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}` at the beginning of `\newbibmacro{cite:full:article}{%` and `\endgroup` at the end.