# Removing title from bib: Undefined control sequence \AtEveryBibitem

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to remove the title from the references. I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,usenames,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage
[
        a4paper,
        left=2cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=1.5cm,
        bottom=1.5cm,
]
{geometry}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOCUMENT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\cite{bib1}
\bibliography{mini.bib}
\end{document}
```

When I compile, it returns me the error "Undefined control sequence \AtEveryBibitem".
How can I fix this? I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233581/ateverybibitem-clearfieldtitle-in-beamer?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer.

Comment: `\AtEveryBibitem` is a `biblatex` command, but you've not loaded `biblatex`: what is the intention here?

Comment: You are not using `biblatex`. You use classical BibTeX and `\bibliographystyle` to generate your bibliography. As such you cannot use `biblatex` solutions with `biblatex` commands like `\AtEveryBibitem`. If you want to get rid of titles with BibTeX, you'll have to modify a renamed copy of the `.bst` file you use (`unsrt.bst` in your case).